# How to find all distinct relationships and count of relations?

Tags: memgraphdb

I know that I can get total number of relationships using `MATCH () -[r]-> () RETURN count(r) AS quantity`. How I can get count per relationship type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following query to get count per relationship type:

```
MATCH ()-[e]->() RETURN type(e), count(e) as quantity
```